# Google Maps API - loadGeoJson based on a checkbox status

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps-api-3

I have this Google Map overlay file.

Overlay - https://api.myjson.com/bins/ge7q4

```js
function initAutocomplete() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 5,
          center: {lat: 49.656963, lng: -112.506664},
    gestureHandling: 'greedy',
  mapTypeControl: false
        });
    
    
   
    
    // Load GeoJson Data Plus Choose Polygon Color


            map.data.loadGeoJson(
            'https://api.myjson.com/bins/ge7q4');
    
    
   map.data.setStyle(function myFunction(feature) {
    var checkBox = document.getElementById("overlayid");
    if (checkBox.checked == true){
        return {
         fillColor: feature.getProperty('COLOR'),
          strokeWeight: 1,
          strokeColor: 'white',
          fillOpacity: 0.4,
          strokeOpacity: 0.7,
          zIndex: 0
   };
    } else {
   return {
         fillColor: feature.getProperty('COLOR'),
          strokeWeight: 1,
          strokeColor: 'black',
          fillOpacity: 0.4,
          strokeOpacity: 0.7,
          zIndex: 0
   };
    }
  });    
    
   
    

    
   // Infowindow
  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
     zIndex: 2
   });
      map.data.addListener('click', function(event) {
     
   map.data.revertStyle();
   map.data.overrideStyle(event.feature, {strokeWeight: 2, strokeColor: 'black', zIndex: 1});
   
   var CDNAME = event.feature.getProperty('CDNAME');
   var COLOR = event.feature.getProperty('COLOR');
   
   infoWindow.setPosition( event.latLng );
   infoWindow.setOptions( {
    pixelOffset: {width: 0, height: -3}
   });
  
   infoWindow.setContent(
     "CDNAME: <b>" + CDNAME + "</b><br />" + 
     "COLOR: <b>" + COLOR + "</b>"
   ); 
   infoWindow.open(map); 
   
   });
   
   map.data.addListener('clickout', function(event) {
      
    map.data.revertStyle();
    infoWindow.close();
   });
    
   map.data.addListener('mouseover', function(event) {
    
   map.data.revertStyle();
   map.data.overrideStyle(event.feature, {strokeWeight: 2, strokeColor: 'black', zIndex: 1});      
   });

        var markers = [];
        // Listen for the event fired when the user selects a prediction and retrieve
        // more details for that place.
        searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function() {
          var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

          // For each place, get the icon, name and location.
          var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
          places.forEach(function(place) {
            if (!place.geometry) {
              console.log("Returned place contains no geometry");
              return;
            }
     
            if (place.geometry.viewport) {
              // Only geocodes have viewport.
              bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
            } else {
              bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
            }
          });
          map.fitBounds(bounds);
        });
      }
```

```css
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }

#floating-panel {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 25%;
  z-index: 5;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Roboto','sans-serif';
  line-height: 30px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="floating-panel">
<input type="checkbox" id="overlayid" name="overlayname" value="overlayvalue" onclick="myFunction()" checked="checked">Border Color<br>
</div>
    <div id="map"></div>
        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete"
         async defer></script>
```

I want to have the ability to toggle border color from white to black by checking/unchecking checkbox.

Right now it only works if I change the status of the checkbox manually in code.

I assuming it has something to do with return function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get a javascript error with the posted code `Uncaught ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined`.  To use that function in the click listener of an HTML element (your checkbox), it needs to be defined in the global scope.   It also can't take any arguments.  I would suggest:

1. rename that function to `styleFunc`, and move it out of the `initAutocomplete` function:

```
function styleFunc(feature) {
  var checkBox = document.getElementById("overlayid");
  if (checkBox.checked == true) {
    return {
      fillColor: feature.getProperty('COLOR'),
      strokeWeight: 1,
      strokeColor: 'white',
      fillOpacity: 0.4,
      strokeOpacity: 0.7,
      zIndex: 0
    };
  } else {
    return {
      fillColor: feature.getProperty('COLOR'),
      strokeWeight: 1,
      strokeColor: 'black',
      fillOpacity: 0.4,
      strokeOpacity: 0.7,
      zIndex: 0
    };
  }
}
```

2. create another function (`stylFeatures` which styles all the objects in the GeoJson data layer, call that in the onclick event of the checkbox:

```
function styleFeatures() {
  map.data.setStyle(styleFunc);
}
```

3. call that in your HTML:

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/oqwxu0et/1/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

**code snippet:**

```js
var map;

function initAutocomplete() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 5,
    center: {
      lat: 49.656963,
      lng: -112.506664
    },
    gestureHandling: 'greedy',
    mapTypeControl: false
  });

  // Load GeoJson Data Plus Choose Polygon Color
  map.data.loadGeoJson(
    'https://api.myjson.com/bins/ge7q4');

  map.data.setStyle(styleFunc);

  // Infowindow
  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    zIndex: 2
  });
  map.data.addListener('click', function(event) {
    map.data.revertStyle();
    map.data.overrideStyle(event.feature, {
      strokeWeight: 2,
      strokeColor: 'black',
      zIndex: 1
    });

    var CDNAME = event.feature.getProperty('CDNAME');
    var COLOR = event.feature.getProperty('COLOR');

    infoWindow.setPosition(event.latLng);
    infoWindow.setOptions({
      pixelOffset: {
        width: 0,
        height: -3
      }
    });

    infoWindow.setContent(
      "CDNAME: <b>" + CDNAME + "</b><br />" +
      "COLOR: <b>" + COLOR + "</b>"
    );
    infoWindow.open(map);
  });

  map.data.addListener('clickout', function(event) {
    map.data.revertStyle();
    infoWindow.close();
  });
  map.data.addListener('mouseover', function(event) {
    map.data.revertStyle();
    map.data.overrideStyle(event.feature, {
      strokeWeight: 2,
      strokeColor: 'black',
      zIndex: 1
    });
  });
}

function styleFunc(feature) {
  var checkBox = document.getElementById("overlayid");
  if (checkBox.checked == true) {
    return {
      fillColor: feature.getProperty('COLOR'),
      strokeWeight: 1,
      strokeColor: 'white',
      fillOpacity: 0.4,
      strokeOpacity: 0.7,
      zIndex: 0
    };
  } else {
    return {
      fillColor: feature.getProperty('COLOR'),
      strokeWeight: 1,
      strokeColor: 'black',
      fillOpacity: 0.4,
      strokeOpacity: 0.7,
      zIndex: 0
    };
  }
}

function styleFeatures() {
  map.data.setStyle(styleFunc);
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#floating-panel {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 25%;
  z-index: 5;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Roboto', 'sans-serif';
  line-height: 30px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initAutocomplete"></script>
<div id="floating-panel">
  <input type="checkbox" id="overlayid" name="overlayname" value="overlayvalue" onclick="styleFeatures()" checked="checked">Border Color<br>
</div>
```

```
<input type="checkbox" id="overlayid" name="overlayname" value="overlayvalue" onclick="styleFeatures()" checked="checked">Border Color<br>
```

Comment: Beautiful! Works as expected!